# Meteor package fails to import or not supporting ES6

Tags: meteor, npm, ecmascript-6, atmosphere.js

I'm trying to convert an NPM package into a Meteor package, I forked the repo from github and made changes to it.

Now I'm trying to port it, it depends on, and uses other NPM packages.

Full stack trace for the first file throwing the `SyntaxError`, if I comment the `import` it picks a different file that also has an `import` statement, `maths` is an external NPM package defined as a requirement in my root meteor's app `package.json`

```
(STDERR) in the root directory of your application.
(STDERR) /Users/octohedron/Documents/App/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/my_package.js:1924
(STDERR) import { MyClass } from 'maths/dist/edit';
(STDERR) ^^^^^^    
(STDERR)           
(STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
(STDERR)     at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
(STDERR)     at /Users/octohedron/Documents/App/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:287:30
(STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
(STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/octohedron/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_1.ge5qu0++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
(STDERR)     at /Users/octohedron/Documents/App/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
```

`import { MyClass } from 'maths/dist/edit';` => `maths` is an npm package specified in my `package.json` at the root of my meteor project.

Do I have to manually transpile all this code to vanilla jS to be able to use it in my custom meteor package?

Comment: `import { MyClass } from 'maths/dist/edit';` is just syntactic sugar for `var MyClass = require('maths/dist/edit').MyClass`;

Comment: Try adding `api.use('ecmascript');` in your `package.js` file.

Comment: It's already there

Comment: Maybe it's version is too old? Also, can you check in your `.meteor/versions` if `modules` package is there?

Comment: what modules package? The error is throwing at the import keyword, as if it doesn't support ES6

Comment: This [modules](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/modules) package. It's a Meteor's built-in package which is providing support for ES6 "import/export" features.

Comment: Yea, It's like it's not loading the ES6 transpiler or something, tried with `modules@0.7.6_1` and `modules-runtime@0.7.6_1` as well, I can't port all this code to vanilla javascript, that would take a lot of time and it's silly, why I can't use ES6 features in Meteor packages?

Comment: Could it be that I should wrap the ES6 code between Meteor.isClient ?

Comment: It's really strange it does not work in the first place. I've tried this approach a couple of times and never had any problems with ES6. Can you attach the relevant content of your `package.js` file as well?

Comment: I answered the question, I guess I was importing the wrong files in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/client/` folder doesn't support ES6.